# openssl and listen on random port

Tags: c, network-programming, openssl, server

I trying to find easy way to select and listen on random port. I can iterate on all ports and tries to open each and after this pass fd to BIO, but this solution is too complicated and can be broken. In addition, I search for portable solution.

Instead of that I search for single OpenSSL function, but cann't find any. Is there simple solution like single function call, provided by OpenSSL library.

About my response:

I have trouble while passing "*" or "*:*" to BIO_new_accept and get port number by BIO_get_accept_port. In this case BIO_get_accept_port returns exactly the string I have passing to BIO_new_accept. Any suggestions how to get port number?

Additional edit:

I discovered that I must call BIO_do_accept after call to BIO_new_accept with asterix, but there's error:

140418757990096:error:02003000:system library:getservbyname:system library:b_sock.c:224:service='*'

Comment: Do you mean to say that the server should bind to a port randomly and listen  and not to a specific port? (Like how clients do if not bound specifically)?

Comment: I mean server should bind on first free port. Client know port number, because server run client and set port number to environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I probably found an solution. Because my English is poor, I don't fully understood documentation text.
I read the documentation again and I found a solution!
From site:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_do_accept

> BIO_set_accept_port() uses the string name to set the accept port. The
>   port is represented as a string of the form "host:port", where "host"
>   is the interface to use and "port" is the port. Either or both values
>   can be "*" which is interpreted as meaning any interface or port
>   respectively. "port" has the same syntax as the port specified in
>   BIO_set_conn_port() for connect BIOs, that is it can be a numerical
>   port string or a string to lookup using getservbyname() and a string
>   table.

So I must only pass asterix character to BIO_do_accept.

Passing asterix character to BIO_new_accept didn't work, because BIO_do_accept returns with error. I solve this in this way:

Instead of passing asterix to BIO_new_accept I was increasing int starting from one and do BIO_new_accept for each number.